# Is "swap" the right word for moving files?

Tags: word-request, verbs

I want to describe moving a list of files to another department. What word would be appropriate to use here? Currently I'm using "swap". Please let me know if that's suitable and suggest alternatives.

Comment: It depends on the situation. How are you moving the files? digitally? physically?

Comment: digitally. A file with list of accounts to be moved from one department to another .

Comment: What do you mean by "department" if you're talking digitally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.

Moving things digital may use the word like - *transferring, proceeding from here to there* or simply as we all know - *moving*! Among these, I'd use *transfer* as the system itself might say **transfer complete!**

Swap won't fit here. It means exchange and I don't think that's the case here (or at least in the scenario you mentioned).

> [swap (v)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/swap_1?q=swap) - to give something to somebody and receive something in exchange

Comment: Thanks for your answer . could i use "shift" here ?

Comment: @sankrish you can but then I prefer 'transfer' that has no ambiguity. That's the jargon we use when we transfer files from one place to another, don't we? In fact, the system itself says **transfer complete.**

Comment: But i guess i should stress the accounts inside the file.So its not similar to file transfer alone

Comment: I think it won't affect much. We are giving the name to the *process* and not the location! Whether it's within the setup or outside, if the files are moving from one place to another place, I'd prefer *transfer* and then further clarify from where to where. *shift* is also the word but with more ambiguity.